# Correct exact Element counting from xml with Apply method

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

How to get the row number for an element (here is  `SpatialElement`) if in extracting APPLY method is used?
The main problem is that the present code-method counts the each row (not only  `SpatialElement`'s amount)

Here is the code
(apply method used twice)

DECLARE @xml xml =
'

```
<Parcels>
 <Parcel ID="1">
   <EntitySpatial>
     <SpatialElement>
         <SpelementUnit  PointNum="1">
          <Ordinate X="100.1" Y="-100.1" />
         </SpelementUnit>
         <SpelementUnit  PointNum="2">
          <Ordinate X="100.2" Y="-100.2" />
         </SpelementUnit> 
     </SpatialElement>
     <SpatialElement>
         <SpelementUnit  PointNum="2">
          <Ordinate X="100.3" Y="-100.3" />
         </SpelementUnit>
         <SpelementUnit  PointNum="2">
          <Ordinate X="100.4" Y="-100.4" />
          </SpelementUnit>
         <SpelementUnit  PointNum="3">
          <Ordinate X="100.5" Y="-100.5" />
         </SpelementUnit> 
     </SpatialElement>            
   </EntitySpatial>
 </Parcel>

 <Parcel ID="2">
   <EntitySpatial>
     <SpatialElement>    
         <SpelementUnit  PointNum="1">
          <Ordinate X="200.1" Y="-200.1" />
         </SpelementUnit>
         <SpelementUnit  PointNum="2">
          <Ordinate X="200.2" Y="-200.2" /> 
         </SpelementUnit> 
     </SpatialElement>
   </EntitySpatial>
 </Parcel>
</Parcels>
```

'

```
 INSERT INTO [BD].[dbo].[RowNumber_For_SpatialElement] (        
 
Parcel_ID

-- RN

,SpatialElement_RowLabel
,SpatialElement_RN 

--

,PointNum
,Ordinate_X
,Ordinate_Y

  )

SELECT 

base.value('(@ID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(1000)')

--------- RowNumber counting

,outr.value('.', 'varchar(1000)') as SpatialElement_RowLabel,
   row_number() over(order by base) as SpatialElement_RN

----------

,outr2.value('(@PointNum)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)')
,outr2.value('(*:Ordinate/@X)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)')
,outr2.value('(*:Ordinate/@Y)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)')

FROM @xml.nodes('*:Parcels/*:Parcel') as x(base)

OUTER APPLY base.nodes('*:EntitySpatial/*:SpatialElement') B(outr) 
OUTER APPLY base.nodes('*:EntitySpatial/*:SpatialElement/*:SpelementUnit') C(outr2)
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**
kind of
(the main thing is to keep RowNumber (RN) unique for each SpatialElement within one `Parcel` element or `Parcels`)

```
Parcel_ID  SpatialElement_RowLabel   SpatialElement_RN    PointNum   Ordinate_X  Ordinate_Y          
      1                                  1                   1        100.1      -100.1
      1                                  1                   2        100.2      -100.2
      1                                  1                   3        100.3      -100.3

      1                                  2                   1        100.4      -100.4
      1                                  2                   2        100.5      -100.5

      2                                  1(or3)              1        200.1      -200.1
      2                                  1(or3)              2        200.2      -200.2
```

**Note**

- In case of single sequence of `SpatialElement` within `Parcel`-->`EntitySpatial` the number of records in the table is identical number of xml records. But if there are more 1 of them, multiple multiplication occurs. But in this case, it's ok (and, possibly, inevitable).
- Even would it be an `SpatialElement`'s attribute like "NumberOfRecod" apply method also cross-mixing all of them for all points.
- As a desired result it could be acceptable RowNumber variants Counting all found elements within `Parcel` or continuous counting within `Parcels` element (the latter is possibly preferable).
- (optional) avoid the appearance of the RowLable column (it has empty value) but keeping the count in `SpatialElement_RN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Modifications to your original SQL:

- Removed namespaces wildcards.
- Modified `OUTER APPLY` clauses and their XPath expressions to simulate 1-many relationships.
- Used `DENSE_RANK()` function.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<Parcels>
    <Parcel ID="1">
        <EntitySpatial>
            <SpatialElement>
                <SpelementUnit PointNum="1">
                    <Ordinate X="100.1" Y="-100.1"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
                <SpelementUnit PointNum="2">
                    <Ordinate X="100.2" Y="-100.2"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
            </SpatialElement>
            <SpatialElement>
                <SpelementUnit PointNum="1">
                    <Ordinate X="100.3" Y="-100.3"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
                <SpelementUnit PointNum="2">
                    <Ordinate X="100.4" Y="-100.4"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
                <SpelementUnit PointNum="3">
                    <Ordinate X="100.5" Y="-100.5"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
            </SpatialElement>
        </EntitySpatial>
    </Parcel>
    <Parcel ID="2">
        <EntitySpatial>
            <SpatialElement>
                <SpelementUnit PointNum="1">
                    <Ordinate X="200.1" Y="-200.1"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
                <SpelementUnit PointNum="2">
                    <Ordinate X="200.2" Y="-200.2"/>
                </SpelementUnit>
            </SpatialElement>
        </EntitySpatial>
    </Parcel>
</Parcels>';

SELECT base.value('@ID', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Parcel_ID
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY outr) as SpatialElement_RN
    ,outr2.value('@PointNum', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS PointNum
    ,outr2.value('(Ordinate/@X)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS Ordinate_X
    ,outr2.value('(Ordinate/@Y)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS Ordinate_Y
FROM @xml.nodes('Parcels/Parcel') as x(base)
    OUTER APPLY base.nodes('EntitySpatial/SpatialElement') AS B(outr)
    OUTER APPLY outr.nodes('SpelementUnit') AS C(outr2);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+-------------------+----------+------------+------------+
| Parcel_ID | SpatialElement_RN | PointNum | Ordinate_X | Ordinate_Y |
+-----------+-------------------+----------+------------+------------+
|         1 |                 1 |        1 |      100.1 |     -100.1 |
|         1 |                 1 |        2 |      100.2 |     -100.2 |
|         1 |                 2 |        1 |      100.3 |     -100.3 |
|         1 |                 2 |        2 |      100.4 |     -100.4 |
|         1 |                 2 |        3 |      100.5 |     -100.5 |
|         2 |                 3 |        1 |      200.1 |     -200.1 |
|         2 |                 3 |        2 |      200.2 |     -200.2 |
+-----------+-------------------+----------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: One additional question. Is it easy to modify this code to count RN from 1 in each node (here it means within each `Parcel` node)